# JQuery promise: access to outside variable or passing results to IIFE inside .done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to pass extra value to promise `.done`. The problem is that `console.log(dataToDownload)` always prints `"b"`.

```
var downloadData = {
    'a': 'http://www.aaa.aa?callback=?',
    'b': 'http://www.bbb.bb?callback=?',
}

var promises = [];

for (dataToDownload in downloadData){

    promises.push($.get(downloadData[dataToDownload], {}, null, 'jsonp')
        .done(function(results){

            console.log(dataToDownload)
            console.log(results);

        }))
}

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){

    console.log('Downloaded!')

})
```

I've tried IIFE:

```
 .done( (function(id){

            console.log(id)
            console.log(results);

        })(dataToDownload); ))
```

But I don't know how to pass 'results' to IIFE.

What would be the best solution to be able to access both: `results` and `dataToDownload` inside `.done`?

Comment: You can already access `dataToDownload`, it's in its lexical scope...

Comment: Your issue may be this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @elclanrs: `console.log(dataToDownload)` in the first example prints 'b' twice

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a duplicate of the question I linked above.

Comment: @elclanrs: yes, problem is somehow related, symptoms are the same, but how to solve it in my case (JQuery promise + `.done`)?

Comment: The issue is the same, you gotta wrap your code within the loop in an IIFE, or easier, just use `Object.keys(downloadData).forEach(function(dataToDownload){...`.

Comment: Could you provide full answer, so it will be simpler to test it

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(downloadData[dataToDownload])`